# Apache Ignite.NET TryEnter on ICacheLock returns false on network communication error instead of throwing exception

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

Here's the scenario.

1. Network issue occurs
2. Apache Ignite.NET cluster has 1 node which gets segmented. I can see this in the logs, the node in question logs NodeSegmented event
3. On the segmented node if you get a **ICacheLock** object from a **ICache** object and then try to enter lock with **TryEnter()** you get return value **false**. Not because the cache key is already locked, but strangely what appears to be because of this network segmentation.
4. Restart the segmented node and it re-joins the cluster and works as expected.

Here's the stacktrace I see in the logs when this event occurs:

```
Failed to send unlock request to node (will make best effort to complete): TcpDiscoveryNode [id=d8b54715-4597-410c-a027-3c76d28ec7f1, addrs=[10.20.18.104], sockAddrs=[10.20.18.104:49100], discPort=49100, order=3174, intOrder=1590, lastExchangeTime=1523347291158, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:bdaeecca, isClient=false]] Native:[class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (node may have left the grid or TCP connection cannot be established due to firewall issues) [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=d8b54715-4597-410c-a027-3c76d28ec7f1, addrs=[10.20.18.104], sockAddrs=[/10.20.18.104:49100], discPort=49100, order=3174, intOrder=1590, lastExchangeTime=1523347291158, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:bdaeecca, isClient=false], topic=TOPIC_CACHE, msg=GridDhtUnlockRequest [], policy=2]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:1651)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:1715)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtTransactionalCacheAdapter.removeLocks(GridDhtTransactionalCacheAdapter.java:1652)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLockFuture.undoLocks(GridDhtLockFuture.java:425)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLockFuture.onComplete(GridDhtLockFuture.java:719)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLockFuture.onDone(GridDhtLockFuture.java:703)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLockFuture.onDone(GridDhtLockFuture.java:82)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:461)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridCompoundFuture.apply(GridCompoundFuture.java:129)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridCompoundFuture.apply(GridCompoundFuture.java:45)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:382)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.unblock(GridFutureAdapter.java:346)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.unblockAll(GridFutureAdapter.java:334)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:494)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:473)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.onDone(GridFutureAdapter.java:461)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLockFuture$MiniFuture.onResult(GridDhtLockFuture.java:1191)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLockFuture.map(GridDhtLockFuture.java:959)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLockFuture.onOwnerChanged(GridDhtLockFuture.java:655)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMvccManager.notifyOwnerChanged(GridCacheMvccManager.java:226)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMvccManager.access$200(GridCacheMvccManager.java:80)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMvccManager$3.onOwnerChanged(GridCacheMvccManager.java:163)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.checkOwnerChanged(GridCacheMapEntry.java:3669)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.GridDistributedCacheEntry.readyLock(GridDistributedCacheEntry.java:469)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLockFuture.readyLocks(GridDhtLockFuture.java:567)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLockFuture.map(GridDhtLockFuture.java:764)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedCache.lockAllAsync0(GridDhtColocatedCache.java:1066)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedCache.lockAllAsync(GridDhtColocatedCache.java:937)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.lockLocally(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:1171)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.mapAsPrimary(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:1282)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.map0(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:852)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.map(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:813)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.mapOnTopology(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:772)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.map(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:720)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedCache.lockAllAsync(GridDhtColocatedCache.java:664)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.GridDistributedCacheAdapter.lockAllAsync(GridDistributedCacheAdapter.java:117)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.lockAll(GridCacheAdapter.java:3258)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheLockImpl.tryLock(CacheLockImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheLockImpl.tryLock(CacheLockImpl.java:130)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCache.processInStreamOutLong(PlatformCache.java:524)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformTargetProxyImpl.inStreamOutLong(PlatformTargetProxyImpl.java:65)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to send message to remote node: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=d8b54715-4597-410c-a027-3c76d28ec7f1, addrs=[10.20.18.104], sockAddrs=[10.20.18.104:49100], discPort=49100, order=3174, intOrder=1590, lastExchangeTime=1523347291158, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:bdaeecca, isClient=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2544)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2480)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:1643)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=d8b54715-4597-410c-a027-3c76d28ec7f1, addrs=[10.20.18.104:47100]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3179)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2763)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2655)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2516)
    ... 43 more
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to address [addr=10.20.18.104:47100, err=Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3184)
        ... 46 more
    Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.safeHandshake(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3438)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3044)
        ... 46 more
]
```

**And a slightly different one:**

```
Level: [Error], Message:[<ResoDupCheck> Failed to send unlock request [keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=482, val=201804141800-2-190327-110016411351-pat-clarkson-greene, hasValBytes=true]], n=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=d8b54715-4597-410c-a027-3c76d28ec7f1, addrs=[10.20.18.104], sockAddrs=[10.20.18.104:49100], discPort=49100, order=3174, intOrder=1590, lastExchangeTime=1523347291158, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:bdaeecca, isClient=false]]] Native:[class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (node may have left the grid or TCP connection cannot be established due to firewall issues) [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=d8b54715-4597-410c-a027-3c76d28ec7f1, addrs=[10.20.18.104], sockAddrs=[10.20.18.104:49100], discPort=49100, order=3174, intOrder=1590, lastExchangeTime=1523347291158, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:bdaeecca, isClient=false], topic=TOPIC_CACHE, msg=GridNearUnlockRequest [super=GridDistributedUnlockRequest [keys=[UserKeyCacheObjectImpl [part=482, val=201804141800-2-190327-110016411351-pat-clarkson-greene, hasValBytes=true]], super=GridDistributedBaseMessage [ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=121528584, order=1523348164577, nodeOrder=3178], committedVers=[], rolledbackVers=[], cnt=1, super=GridCacheIdMessage [cacheId=-1009505448]]]], policy=2]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:1651)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:1715)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedCache.removeLocks(GridDhtColocatedCache.java:877)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.undoLocks(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:383)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.onComplete(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:575)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.onDone(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:559)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.map(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:819)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.mapOnTopology(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:772)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.map(GridDhtColocatedLockFuture.java:720)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.colocated.GridDhtColocatedCache.lockAllAsync(GridDhtColocatedCache.java:664)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.GridDistributedCacheAdapter.lockAllAsync(GridDistributedCacheAdapter.java:117)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.lockAll(GridCacheAdapter.java:3258)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheLockImpl.tryLock(CacheLockImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheLockImpl.tryLock(CacheLockImpl.java:130)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCache.processInStreamOutLong(PlatformCache.java:524)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformTargetProxyImpl.inStreamOutLong(PlatformTargetProxyImpl.java:65)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to send message to remote node: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=d8b54715-4597-410c-a027-3c76d28ec7f1, addrs=[10.20.18.104], sockAddrs=[10.20.18.104:49100], discPort=49100, order=3174, intOrder=1590, lastExchangeTime=1523347291158, loc=false, ver=2.1.0#20170720-sha1:bdaeecca, isClient=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2544)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2480)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:1643)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to node (is node still alive?). Make sure that each ComputeTask and cache Transaction has a timeout set in order to prevent parties from waiting forever in case of network issues [nodeId=d8b54715-4597-410c-a027-3c76d28ec7f1, addrs=[10.20.18.104:47100]]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3179)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2763)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2655)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2516)
    ... 18 more
    Suppressed: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to connect to address [addr=10.20.18.104:47100, err=Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3184)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to read remote node recovery handshake (connection closed).
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.safeHandshake(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3438)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3044)
        ... 21 more
]
```

My main question is, why doesn't the **ICacheLock** throw exception? By returning false, it incorrectly tells me that the cache key is already locked. Because I have no way of knowing that the false is due to some network issue or due to the fact that the cache key is already locked.

My current solution is: add listener to the NodeSegment local event and shutdown/restart the Ignite node. With a defensive backup plan of using a circuit breaker from Polly to check if more than 50% of requests fail to grab the lock within a 30 second period. Which should be an unlikely case, and will result in skipping the locking call and proceeding without (in a degraded state).

Am I missing something in my Ignite.NET configuration?

Am I missing some understanding about how Ignite works?

Is there some programmatic way of knowing why the TryEnter call returned false and make a decision as to how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Ignite doesn't propagate an exception from Java part to .NET one. If we try to do the same in Java API, tryEnter() throws javax.cache.CacheException.

I've created the Jira ticket to resolve this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-8247

Also, please make sure that the key (which you try to lock) exists in the cache.

As a workaround, you can add your own listeners for ClientDisconnected, ClientReconnected events. Here is an example:

```
class TryEnterIssue
{
    public static bool ClientDisconnected = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration() { ... };

        using (var ignite = Ignition.Start(cfg))
        {
            ...

            ICache<int, string> cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<int, string>(cacheConfiguration);

            ignite.ClientDisconnected += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                ClientDisconnected = true;

                Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected.");
            };

            ignite.ClientReconnected += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                ClientDisconnected = false;

                Console.WriteLine("Client reconnected.");
            };

            ...

            ICacheLock lock1 = cache.Lock(1);
            try
            {
                if (!lock1.TryEnter())
                {
                    if (ClientDisconnected)
                    {
                        // Client is disconnected.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Unable to acquire a lock.
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lock1.Exit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ...
            }

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for creating a ticket for this to be looked into. Though your workaround suggestion won't work in my case since the ClientDisconnected, ClientReconnected events are documented as only working when if the node is running in ClientMode. My nodes are running in server mode.